# How do I ensure that $\sup_{p\ge 1}||f||_p < \infty$ for every $f \in L_\infty$?

Tags: measure-theory

> What condition must one put on a measure space $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ in order to ensure that every $f \in L_\infty$ satisfies $$\displaystyle \sup_{p\ge 1}||f||_p < \infty?$$

Here are some things that I have written down so far just to give some idea of my trail of thought on this so far:

Firstly, we will require, for every $f \in L_\infty$, that $$||f||_p =\left(\int|f|^p d\mu \right)^{\frac{1}{p}}<\infty,$$ for every $p \ge 1$ (since we want the supremum of them all to be finite, we require it to be finite for every $p\ge 1$).

In light of what I have above, this then leads me to believe that we require that, if $f \in L_\infty$, then we will also require $f \in L_p$ for every $p\ge 1$.

In other words, we will require $f \in L_\infty$ to be integrable with respect to any $p$-norm in $L_p$ for every $p\ge 1$.

Is my trail of thought correct so far?

Also, if my thought process is correct thus far, is there a specific condition that we can apply to the measure space $(X, \Sigma, \mu)$ to ensure that for every $f \in L_\infty$, we have that $f \in L_p$ for all $p\ge 1$?

Comment: $$\mu(X)\ \text{finite}.$$

Answer (score 5):

The constant function $1 \in L^\infty$, and $\|1\|_p = \mu(X)^{1/p}$
You need $\mu(X) < \infty$, i.e. $\mu$ must be a finite measure, and then
$\sup_{p \ge 1} \|1\|_p = \max(1, \mu(X)) < \infty$.  Conversely, if 
$\mu$ is a finite measure, for any $f \in L^\infty$ you have 
$|f| \le \|f \|_\infty 1$ a.e., so that $\|f\|_p \le \|f\|_\infty \|1\|_p$.  Thus this is sufficient as well as necessary.